# check if unit-test has passed

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I developed a crawler and it's unit-tests (mainly to validate XPATHs). I want to run specific unit-tests before script execution in order to be sure that HTML structure has not changed and existing XPATHs still working. I don't want the output of unit-test, just a flag: passed or failed.

for example:

tests.py:

```
import unittest

class CrwTst(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        [..]
```

crawler.py

```
class Crawler(object):
    def action_1(self):
        [..]
```

and I want to work like:

```
if CrwTst.test_1() is True:
    Crawler.action_1()
```

Comment: Tests raise Exceptions (usually AssertionError) when they fail. So as long as you don't catch that error you can probably do `test_my_thing(); action1()`. Also ZdaR is right, this seems an odd use of unit tests (which are intended to test your code itself, not to validate data you pass to your code).

Comment: Why create a test case for this, You can create a validation function which either returns `True` or `False`

Comment: @ZdaR I have many test cases and I think it's better to keep this kind of validations with other unit-tests. I'm newbie to unit-testing development and maybe you are right.

Comment: @TomDalton I'm trying to import CrwTst to crawler.py `from tests import CrwTst` and I'm getting import error `ImportError: cannot import name CrwTst`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially do this:

**crawler.py**

```
import unittest
from tests import CrwTst

if unittest.TextTestRunner().run(CrwTst('test_1')).wasSuccessful():
    Crawler.action_1()
```

Note however that you may run into an issue with circular imports, because your test presumably already depends on `Crawler`, and what you are looking to do will make the `Crawler` depend on the test. This will likely manifest itself as `ImportError: cannot import name CrwTst`.

To resolve that, you can dynamically import the `CrwTst`.

**crawler.py**

```
import unittest

def function_that_runs_crawler():
    from tests import CrwTst  # Dynamically import to resolve circular ref

    if unittest.TextTestRunner().run(CrwTst('test_1')).wasSuccessful():
        Crawler.action_1()
```